# Stop Visual Studio from searching text in some file types in project/solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a number of large data files that I included in projects attributed with copy-on-newer. When I search for a string in the project or solution, I would like it to not search these large files, since it slows the process way down. Is there are way to have these files in the project, but exempted from the text search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a wildcard pattern in the search box to include/exclude files of different types.  Anything other than `*.*` will exclude files not in the list.

Comment: I can see how that includes file, but how does it exclude? Other than the obvious by not being included? I guess, I'm only looking for source usually, so....I can add all of those types from the drop-down.

Comment: If you specify, for example: *.aspx, then anything without an .aspx extension will be excluded.  The box comes with a pre-populated set of includes, which you can customize.